# extract script as plain text using selenium with python

Tags: html, python-2.7, selenium-webdriver, web-scraping

I have been trying to extract a link that is inside a script tag. But I can't seem to do it. The HTML looks as follows.

```
<script>
 if(!window.runParams) {
 window.runParams = {};
 }
 window.runParams.descUrl="www.IWANTTHIS.com";
...
```

I was planning on extracting the script as plain text then cleaning it up so I can navigate to it. but I can't seem to extract it. When I run 
link.get_attribute("script") I get the response None! How can i extract the link? is there a better way?

Comment: share more code

Comment: I used get_attribute(innerHTML) instead of script. that solved the problem.